# Teamcity, Error collecting changes

Tags: svn, centos6, teamcity

Created a brand new TeamCity build project and configuration along w/ a new VCS root and receive the following errors on the first check for revisions

TeamCity 8.0.6 (build 27767) running on CentOS 6.

**Failed to start build #2 on Web Cluster #1**

```
Failed to collect changes, error: Error collecting changes for VCS repository '"rvdealers-trunk" {instance id=9, parent internal id=9, parent id=NationalRvDealers_RvdealersTrunk, description: "svn: svn://svn.masteredge.corp/rvdealers/trunk"}'
Unable to get SVN log entries for: svn://svn.masteredge.corp/rvdealers/trunk; range: RR[9_2014/02/24 23:19:19 -0500 => 11_2014/02/24 23:48:03 -0500]@a3daeacc-e5f5-4bd8-a1b2-caa81242066d; revisions: 9..11
```

**VCS problem: rvdealers-trunk**

```
Error collecting changes for VCS repository '"rvdealers-trunk" {instance id=9, parent internal id=9, parent id=NationalRvDealers_RvdealersTrunk, description: "svn: svn://svn.masteredge.corp/rvdealers/trunk"}'
Unable to get SVN log entries for: svn://svn.masteredge.corp/rvdealers/trunk; range: RR[9_2014/02/24 23:19:19 -0500 => 11_2014/02/24 23:48:03 -0500]@a3daeacc-e5f5-4bd8-a1b2-caa81242066d; revisions: 9..11
```

I've tried deleting and recreating the vcs root, build configuration, and even the project, this occurs as soon as TeamCity tries checking for revisions.

The build agent trying to run the build resides on a different server, running Windows 2008. This project is .NET so the TeamCity host is unable to run the build.

TeamCity and the SVN server are both running on the same server.

I can post the stack-trace if anybody thinks it might be helpful, just didn't because it's super long. I've got 4 other projects setup successfully, exactly the same as this, but this is the only one that doesn't work.

Comment: added another new repository to my svn server, configured a project, vcs root, and build configuration using the exact same settings as my above problem and everything worked just fine. Since the one above was a newly created and imported repository, I deleted it from svn and recreated it and everything seems to be working fine. No idea what happened or why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this worked for me, but I went into the VCS config and changed the SVN Client version from 1.6 to 1.7, and then everything started working.

Comment: interesting... unfortunately I corrected the issue by simply recreating the svn repository.